# Prolog - a program that finds a group of values that sum to a particular value

Tags: prolog

I want to make a program that receives 3 arguments:

1. list1 of coins for example: `[5,2,1]`
2. value - sum we want to get
3. list of coins that sum to that particular value - this list is a sub-list of list1
   (it's allowed to repeat the same element , for ex: to reach 4, we can have the list `[2,2]`)

so the program should do 2 things:

1. `change([5,2,1],4,[2,2])` will return `Yes`   (cause 2+2 =4)
2. `change([5,2],6,Coins)` will return `Coins = [2,2,2]`

this is my attempt:

```
change(_,0,Res).
change([X|Xs],Sum,Cs):- Sum <X, change(Xs,Sum,Cs).
change([X|Y],Sum,[X|Res]):- Sum>=X, Sum2 is Sum - X, change([X|Y],Sum2,Res).
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? First rule should be `change(_,0,[]).` (`[]` instead of `Res`).

Comment: well.. it doesn't work the way I did it..

Comment: why do u have to change it to []? I don't think so. u should get 0 once u got the required set to to get the value..

Comment: Because for a zero sum you need no coin (an empty list of coins).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `Res` to `[]` for the last argument of the first rule. In addition, you should add a cut operator in the same rule to avoid getting the same result multiple times.

```
change(_, 0, []):-!.
change([X|Y], Sum, [X|Res]):-
    Sum >= X, !, % remove the cut operator to get all solutions
    Sum2 is Sum - X,
    change([X|Y], Sum2, Res).
change([_|Xs],Sum,Cs):-
    change(Xs, Sum, Cs).
```

Comment: I am getting a syntax error when I run it... and you cannot assume that the list is sorted.

Comment: I'm sure the syntax error is not because of the code in the answer. But do you need all solutions or just the one with the biggest coins?

Comment: So it's working on your computer fine ? I need it to produce the first answer .. not necessarily with the big coins..

Comment: I fixed the syntax error... but when I run change({2,5},4,{2,2}). I get false

Comment: That is because lists in Prolog are enclosed in square brackets. Try `change([2,5], 4, [2,2]).` That should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

'guessing' an element from a list can be done with member/2.

Just pay care to termination

```
change(_,0,[]).
change(Coins,Sum,[C|Cs]) :-
   Sum > 0, member(C, Coins), Rest is Sum-C, change(Coins,Rest,Cs).
```